# QoS=1 with MqttAsyncClient subscription miss messages

Tags: android, mqtt, paho

I have foreground service acting as MQTT client. I'm using `MqttAsyncClient mqttClient` for this purpose.
I'm using `QoS=1` on subscribe to topic:

```
mqttClient.subscribe("sensors/s1/", 1);
```

But in case my phone gets offline for some period of time it miss current period messages. Whole code is below.

Im my another application I'm using `MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient` and in this case QoS=1 brings all missed messages.

```
mqttAndroidClient.subscribe(topic, 1, null, new IMqttActionListener() {...})
```

Why subscription with `MqttAsyncClient` with QoS=1 not retrieves all messages?

Whole code :

```
public class MqttGndService extends Service {

    private String ip="ssl:myserver",port="8887";
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private Handler mHandler;


    private static final String TAG = "mqttservice";
    private static boolean hasWifi = false;
    private static boolean hasMmobile = false;
    private ConnectivityManager mConnMan;
    private volatile IMqttAsyncClient mqttClient;
    private String uniqueID;


    class MQTTBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            IMqttToken token;
            boolean hasConnectivity = false;
            boolean hasChanged = false;
            NetworkInfo infos[] = mConnMan.getAllNetworkInfo();
            for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
                if (infos[i].getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE")) {
                    if ((infos[i].isConnected() != hasMmobile)) {
                        hasChanged = true;
                        hasMmobile = infos[i].isConnected();
                    }
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v( infos[i].getTypeName() + " is " + infos[i].isConnected());
                } else if (infos[i].getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI")) {
                    if ((infos[i].isConnected() != hasWifi)) {
                        hasChanged = true;
                        hasWifi = infos[i].isConnected();
                    }
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v(infos[i].getTypeName() + " is " + infos[i].isConnected());
                }
            }
            hasConnectivity = hasMmobile || hasWifi;
            Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v( "hasConn: " + hasConnectivity + " hasChange: " + hasChanged + " - " + (mqttClient == null || !mqttClient.isConnected()));
            if (hasConnectivity && hasChanged && (mqttClient == null || !mqttClient.isConnected())) {
                Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Ready to connect");
                doConnect();
                Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("do connect done");

            } else
            {
                Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Connection not possible");
            }



        }
    }


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MqttGndService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return MqttGndService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public void publish(String topic, MqttMessage message) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);// we create a 'shared" memory where we will share our preferences for the limits and the values that we get from onsensorchanged
        try {

            mqttClient.publish(topic, message);

        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Creating MQTT service");
        mHandler = new Handler();//for toasts
        IntentFilter intentf = new IntentFilter();
        setClientID();
        intentf.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(new MQTTBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
        mConnMan = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v( "onConfigurationChanged()");
        android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Service onDestroy");

    }


    private void setClientID() {
        uniqueID = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("uniqueID=" + uniqueID);

    }


    private void doConnect() {
        String broker = ip + ":" + port;
        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("mqtt_doConnect()");
        IMqttToken token;
        MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
        options.setCleanSession(true);
        options.setMaxInflight(100);//handle more messages!!so as not to disconnect
        options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
        options.setConnectionTimeout(1000);
        options.setKeepAliveInterval(300);
        options.setUserName("cc50e3e91bf4");
        options.setPassword("b".toCharArray());

        try {
            options.setSocketFactory(SocketFactoryMQ.getSocketFactory(this,""));
        } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("set socket factory done");
        try {


            mqttClient = new MqttAsyncClient(broker, uniqueID, new MemoryPersistence());
            token = mqttClient.connect(options);
            token.waitForCompletion(3500);

            mqttClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
                @Override
                public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
                    try {
                        mqttClient.disconnectForcibly();
                        mqttClient.connect();
                    } catch (MqttException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage msg) throws Exception {
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("Message arrived from topic " + topic+ "  msg: " + msg );



                }

                @Override
                public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
                    System.out.println("published");
                }
            });
            Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("will subscribe");
            mqttClient.subscribe("sensors/s1/", 1);



        } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
            Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("general connect exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            switch (e.getReasonCode()) {
                case MqttException.REASON_CODE_BROKER_UNAVAILABLE:
                    mHandler.post(new ToastRunnable("WE ARE OFFLINE BROKER_UNAVAILABLE!", 1500));
                    break;
                case MqttException.REASON_CODE_CLIENT_TIMEOUT:
                    mHandler.post(new ToastRunnable("WE ARE OFFLINE CLIENT_TIMEOUT!", 1500));
                    break;
                case MqttException.REASON_CODE_CONNECTION_LOST:
                    mHandler.post(new ToastRunnable("WE ARE OFFLINE CONNECTION_LOST!", 1500));
                    break;
                case MqttException.REASON_CODE_SERVER_CONNECT_ERROR:
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v( "c " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                case MqttException.REASON_CODE_FAILED_AUTHENTICATION:
                    Intent i = new Intent("RAISEALLARM");
                    i.putExtra("ALLARM", e);
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("b " + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                default:
                    Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v( "a " + e.getMessage() +" "+ e.toString());
            }
        }
        mHandler.post(new ToastRunnable("WE ARE ONLINE!", 500));

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("onStartCommand");
        String input = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_ID);
        Timber.tag(Utils.TIMBER_TAG).v("onStartCommand "+ input);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Example Service")
                .setContentText(input)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        startForeground(1, notification);


        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
        wakeLock.acquire();


        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting cleansession to true (`options.setCleanSession(true)`); from the docs for [setCleanSession](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttConnectOptions.html#setCleanSession-boolean-):

> If set to true the client and server will not maintain state across restarts of the client, the server or the connection. This means
>
> - Message delivery to the specified QOS cannot be maintained if the client, server or connection are restarted
> - The server will treat a subscription as non-durable

I think that the [mqtt specs](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Ref362965194) state this more clearly:

> If CleanSession is set to 1, the Client and Server MUST discard any previous Session and start a new one. This Session lasts as long as the Network Connection. State data associated with this Session MUST NOT be reused in any subsequent Session

So when your application looses the connection the session is discarded and new messages will not be queued up for delivery. In addition unless you resubscribe when the connection comes back up you will not receive any additional messages.

However be aware that if you set cleansession to false then any new messages received while your client is offline will be queued for delivery (subject to the configuration of the broker) and this might not be what you want to happen if the client could be offline for a long time.